# Flask: How to retain a value in a variable for a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

i'm making a chatbot on messenger platform and i'm asking the user a series of questions.But, when the user answers the first question, it goes directly to the fallback intent in Api.AI and i have to keep answering the same question untill it goes to the next question. 
I thought setting a sessionID will fix the issue but it didn't.

```
ai = ApiAI(os.environ["APIAI_TOKEN"])
req = ai.text_request()
    req.session_id = str(uuid.uuid1(int(str(senderID)[0:15])))
```

As it turns out the  output of the *uuid1* changes sometimes when a new request(when user answers the question) even if the senderID is the same(senderID is the user ID sent by facebook).So, i'm trying to save the value from uuid1 to a dictionary and if a user answer's the first question the new request will frist check the dictionary for the senderID and if it already exist it will not generate a new uuid for the same senderID. 
But the problem is sometimes when a new request(from the same user) hits heroku, the values from the dictionary is gone. This doesn't happens everytime but about 90% of the time.
Here's the logs of a new request.

```
2017-11-18T09:43:03.784670+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=website.com request_id=ab6d6488-0343-4c68-9b2a-d6faf2ee2302 fwd="173.252.123.140" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=633ms status=200 bytes=161 protocol=https
```

What should i do to retain the value. Is there any other approach?
I'm a newbie and i've being stuck in this problem for a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary might not be tied to a session and may run out of scope and get cleared off from memory. So anything you store there won't be reliably persisted. There are two ways to solve this problem. The first is to use a seperate cache server like Redis to store your values and the second is to use cache tools in Flask itself.

If you plan on using an external redis server, you can do something like the code below

```
import redis

# instantiate the redis db
REDIS_HOST = <REDIS_HOST>
REDIS_PORT = <REDIS_PORT>
redis_db = redis.StrictRedis(host=REDIS_HOST,port=REDIS_PORT)

key = sender_id
event = {}
event["uuid"] = uuid1
event["sender_id"] = sender_id
redis_db.delete(key) #remove old keys
redis_db.hmset(key, event)
redis_db.expire(key, 259200) #3 days (you can set your own expire time in seconds
```

You can check the cache to see if a value exists using

```
key = sender_id
if redis_db.exists(key):
    event = redis_db.hgetall(key)
```

The second way is to use flask's cache tools with either a SimpleCache or an LRUCache. Below is an example of using SimpleCache

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import SimpleCache
cache = SimpleCache()

key = sender_id
event = {}
event["uuid"] = uuid1
event["sender_id"] = sender_id

cache.set(key,event,timeout=259200) # 3 days
```

The cache values can later be retrived with

```
key = sender_id
event = cache.get(key)
```

However you need to keep in mind that if you use the second option of using the cache tools on the same server then everytime your server restarts you will lose the values but they should be available throughout a session nevertheless.

Comment: when the server restarts won't  i lose the values from redis as well?

Comment: If you install it on the same machine, yes. But most people I know, atleast new developers use some sort of a cloud service for redis (azure,aws etc) so because it's running on a different server they wouldn't reset.

Also if the answer helped you please accept it